# Best way to make a complex shape on head character or apply material to part of a mesh

Tags: modeling, mesh, materials

I am a beginner with Blender and try to create a robot for a personnal project.

Which looks like this :

[image]

As you can see, there is two part on the head of my character. The face (the white part) and the hair (the black part). I search the best way to put my black material on the head of my robot. But I don't know the best way to make this complex shape on my mesh.

My mesh :

[image]

I tried to make it with the knife tool, but the subdivision modifier deform my mesh.

What is the best way to do this without deforming my mesh ? Did I need to separate my head in two meshs (the face and the hair) [I tried but it also deform my mesh] ? Is there a better way to apply material to a specific part of a mesh ?

Thanks in advance for your time :)

My blend file :

[image]

Comment: Have you thought about an image texture? You could keep your mesh as it is...

Comment: So the best way will be to paint a texture directly on my mesh ? For now, I apply materials to my mesh with select faces in edit mode.

Comment: I'm not saying that it's the best way, it may be a solution

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the *Project from View* unwrap? In that case you could prepare your front an back image and put the UVs over it:

[image]

[image]

You could also cut the topology with a knife and give different materials to the faces, use a *Shrinkwrap* modifier to make the sphere stick to another one underneath:

[image]

[image]

To fix your current file, put the *Subdivision Surface* under the *Shrinkwrap*, and in the *Shrinkwrap* choose *Wrap Method > Nearest Surface Point*, and a bit of *Offset*. You could add a *Solidify* modifier under the *Shrinkwrap* to give it thickness but you'll need to change the topology a bit:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help moonboots :)
I tried with the second option but the shrinkwrap modifier give me a weird result, the hair mesh is below/inside of my head mesh. I changed parameters of shrinwrap modifier, but it doesn't work.

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: I edited my first post to add the blend file

Comment: I see 2 objects, one for the head, of the hair, didn't you want to use the same mesh for both the head and hair?

Comment: When i used the knife tool on the head mesh it deform it with bumps (due to the new vertices). So i tried on an other way. But if i can have the same object for the head and the hair it will be great.

Comment: Here is my file: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=aAYPOEWz" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/aAYPOEWz/) You need to use a Shrinkwrap to make sure that your sphere keeps its shape when you add vertices

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140798/discussion-between-moonboots-and-pitwo).

Comment: I've opened you file and made some changes, please check my edit